# .gitignore File Not Working With Bonobo

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, bonobo

I set up a Bonobo Git server in IIS and have it working on my local computer. However, the .gitignore file is not working. I'm using the GitHub Windows client and [this ignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). I want the bin and obj folders ignored, but they are showing up as changed folders every time I do a build in Visual Studio. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are showing up as *changed* (and not added), they were already in the repository before you added the .gitignore file. So you need to remove them from the repo by either a) deleting them from your local box and committing, or b) using `git rm --cached` on them.

Comment: Thank was the issue. I deleted repository and started new without the bin and obj folders. Worked perfectly.